# A chrome extension that can detect any typing in any element, not only limited to textarea/input, and print the typed text to the console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to make a chrome extension log any text i type on screen, anywhere in the chrome tab, on any URL
No matter what I do, it doesnt console log anything at all.
I dont want to use the input or textarea elements, as it may fail for the websites that dont use it.

here's what my 3 files look like

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Keystroke Listener",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["scripting", "tabs"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
  }
}
```

background.js

```
console.log('Background script is running');

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    if (!tab.url.startsWith('chrome://')) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        files: ['contentScript.js']
      });
    }
  });
  
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(request.data);
      console.log("Received message from script in tab ", sender.tab);
      
      let responseData = {message: "Received your message"};
      sendResponse(responseData);
  });
```

contentScript.js

```
console.log('Content script has been injected');

let typedMessage = '';

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    typedMessage += e.key;
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log('Sending message:', typedMessage);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ data: typedMessage });
        typedMessage = '';
    }
});
```

I am looking at the right console & all I see is "Background script is running" on the console, but not the text Im typing in the active tab.

\

What am I doing wrong here?
I want to do something like how Grammarly is able to do, it detects any typing happening on screen & is able to read the typed text & give suggestions for it.
I just want to be able to read the typed text.

Comment: Your code starts working only after you click the extension's icon. If you want it to work by default then remove chrome.action.onClicked and declare the content script in manifest.json.